# how to create my own news feed to my website?

Tags: html, web, rss

Well I have a website, and I wanted to add a feature of an articles that I write sometimes for my business, my website is only one page so i want some free plugin, that I will be able to add content without using any code every time, and not start creating a full php website. any idea guys?
thanks..(the website is a full html no joomla or wordpress)

Comment: if your site is just static html, and you dont want to add functionality, the only way is to add more static content to it. html does not provide functionality.

Comment: May I know the website URL please?

Answer (score 1):

The question is absurdly broad, but we can tackle this as best as possible. We're going to assume the following things here:

You know CSS
You know HTML

As such, you're probably aware of how to create tables, columns, and such. So I'll operate under the assumption that you know how to design and create your pages.

Your best bet is to use a PHP include function (or several) that references a file. As such, your index.html will need to become index.php. It's only a single line of PHP so it shouldn't cause issue, and the line itself is fairly simple.

```
<?php include 'directory/file.html';?>
```

Now you'll obviously need to either create your own directory or name your own files. The files referenced do not need to be PHP nor do they need `<html>` or `<body>` tags. They'll be included and styled in the page as is, wherever the PHP include is placed.

This means that you can just edit your included file(s), which will allow you to move these posts around your page as needed simply by moving your PHP function. If you precede the PHP line with a `<p>` tag, you don't even need to add tags into the included file, although I'd recommend doing all of your tagging in the included file rather than the index.php

If there's anything else, comment and let me know. Hope this helped to *some* degree! Again, broad question.